# env command alternative for windows powershell/cmd

Tags: linux, windows, environment-variables

I saw one cool thing in Linux and wondering if it is also available in Windows. In order to run another program in a custom environment without modifying the current one, in Linux we use `env` command, like this:
`env USERNAME="Test" PASSWORD="Test" npm run e2e:test`. Here basically what it does is that e2e tests start running (it can be any type of process in any technology, not just e2e tests in nodejs) but with test user credentials and not with predefined actual user credentials.

How can I achieve this in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this and many other OS related issues by [installing WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) and using it via powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Call `cmd.exe` with a command-line script it will execute in its context. Effectively this:

```
cmd.exe /c "set USERNAME=Test && set PASSWORD=Test && npm run mytest"
```

---

As a full e2e test, try this in a console window:

1. create a little javascript script to output an environment variable:

```
C:\temp> echo console.log(process.env.myvar); >test.js
```

2. Confirm that the environment variable is not set in your shell, and that calling the script also does not find the variable:

```
C:\temp> set myvar
Environment variable myvar not defined

C:\temp> node test.js
undefined
```

3. Now, run the script but set the environment variable in the child process, as described above. Note that the script now sees the value.

```
C:\temp> cmd.exe /c "set myvar=hello && node test.js"
hello
```

4. Confirm that the parent process still doesn't have the variable set.

```
C:\temp> set myvar
Environment variable myvar not defined

C:\temp> node test.js
undefined
```

Comment: I tried it in both powershell and VS code terminal but nothing happened

Comment: It works; I added a full e2e test to see & understand the mechanism. That should help you determine what you're doing wrong.